# Parsing texts between " " on a file to a QString

Tags: qt, foreach, find, qstring, qregexp

I have a text file which looks like this:

> VariableA = 10 VariableB = 20 VariableC = "Hello World"

The code works fine, but my trouble is getting the text strings between " ".

```
QStringList Data;
Data << "VariableA = " << "VariableB = " << "VariableC = ";
QStringList Values;

int VariableA;
int VariableB;
QString VariableC;


foreach(const QString &DataToFind, Data) {
    QRegExp DataExpression(DataToFind);
    int DataStart = DataExpression.indexIn(TextToFind);
    if(DataStart >= 0) {
        int DataLength = DataExpression.matchedLength();
        int ValueSize = 1;
        while(TextToFind.at(DataStart + DataLength + ValueSize) != QChar(' ')) {
            ValueSize++;
        }
        QStringRef DataValue(&TextToFind, DataStart + DataLength, ValueSize);
        Values += DataValue.toString(); 
        DataStart = DataExpression.indexIn(description, DataStart + DataLength);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}

VariableA = Values[0].toInt();
VariableB = Values[1].toInt();
VariableC = Values[2];
```

The issue is that the text on VariableC can have spaces and/or " (double quotes) inside it. So the method I've posted above to retrieve the variables from the file is useless. Since it uses " " to reach end of variable in the file.

How can I retrieve the full text inside the double quotes?

Comment: Is the text file always like that? Are just the values of A, B and X changing?

Comment: There can be more stuff, and yes, A, B and X can change values.

Comment: This might be a bit tricky and depends on the structure of your file. Are you free to change it or is it provided by someone else?

Comment: Also, are you sure you don't want to use QSettings?

Comment: It's provided. But also, there are just 3 "values" to read. Nothing more. I mean "A", "B" and "X" will be always there. But their values can be changed freely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QStringList Data;
Data << "A = " << "B = " << "X = ";

int A;
int B;
QString X;

foreach(const QString &DataToFind, Data) {
    QRegExp DataExpression(DataToFind);
    int DataStart = DataExpression.indexIn(TextToFind);
    if(DataStart >= 0) {
        int DataLength = DataExpression.matchedLength();
        int ValueSize = 1;
        while(TextToFind.at(DataStart + DataLength + ValueSize) != QChar(' ')) {
            ValueSize++;
        }
        QStringRef DataValue(&TextToFind, DataStart + DataLength, ValueSize);
        DataStart = DataExpression.indexIn(description, DataStart + DataLength);
    } else {
        continue;
    }
}
```

This does the work.

Comment: Won't mark as an answer because there's maybe a better way to handle this. I'll leave it open for answers.

Comment: But the issue is if for example X is a string between " ". So this way to parse isn't good.